# How to read the output from a http filter plugin in logstash and store it in elasticsearch index

Tags: http, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a use case where I have to make an external HTTP call to an API endpoint in the **logstash** by passing the input coming from kafka as the body and read the output from the API call and store it in elasticsearch index. Can we achieve this through HTTP filter plugin? If so, my main question is how do we read the output from the API call and index it into elasticsearch.

I also see something called as http poller plugin, is this something that will be of use to me? Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, you can use HTTP Pooler, something like:

```
input {
   # 1. trigger new token requests every hour
   http_poller {
     urls => {
       pipelines => "http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty"
     }
     schedule => { cron => "*/1 * * * *"}
     codec => "json"
     metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"

   }
}
```

then use an elasticsearch output like this:

```
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
        }
```

You can get more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397150/how-to-read-the-output-from-a-http-filter-plugin-in-logstash-and-store-it-in-ela)

I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
input {
  kafka {
  bootstrap_servers => "kafka:29092"
  topics => ["your_topic"]
  codec => json
  request_timeout_ms => 300000
  heartbeat_interval_ms => 1000
  max_poll_interval_ms => 900000
  max_poll_records => 1000
  session_timeout_ms => 600000
  receive_buffer_bytes => 50107200
  send_buffer_bytes => 50107200
        }
  }

filter {
  ruby { code => 'event.set("[@metadata][body]", event.to_hash)' }
  http {
    url => "http://flask:8080/endpoint"
    verb => "POST"
    body => "%{[@metadata][body]}"
    headers => {
       Accept => "application/json"
              }
    body_format => "json"
    target_body => "http_response"
    keepalive => false
    request_timeout => 180
    socket_timeout => 180
       }
  json {
    source => "http_response"
      }
  prune {
     whitelist_names => ["http_response"]
      } 
 }

output {
  stdout {
    codec => json_lines {}
    ecs_compatibility => "v8"
        }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    user => USER_NAME
    password => PASSWORD
    ecs_compatibility => "v8"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    codec => "json_lines"
       }
  }
```

It works by making request for each event in kafka using the API endpoint to make request.

`target_body` is used to store the incoming response, you can use any variable ("http_response") to store the response.

use `json {source => "http_response"}` to store it into the event as json fields, also if you want only the response of the API you can prune the event and keep only `http_response` field using `prune`.